# Hand Tracking not working when build | unity XR Interaction Toolkit

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, openxr

I'm using XR Interaction toolkit hand tracking feature in my project, I noticed that hand tracking not working when i build the project. I read somewhere that i need to change the OpenXR backend type to legacy as a solution, but i can't manage to find where to change this value. So where can I find it ? Or if there's any other alternatives for making hand tracking work on build I'll accept it.

I tried looking for any file having those names "openxr_config.json" or "openxr.ini" but i didn't manage to find anything.

Cordially.